# SNI (Server Name Indication) with tornado

Tags: python, openssl, tornado, sni

As the title states, I'd like to figure out how to use [SNI](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/what-is-sni/) (server name  indication) with the tornado webserver.

I'd like to be able to present a particular certificate based on the hostname of the given request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking more into this I found the solution using a `sni_callback` from `ssl.SSLContext`.

That will give you a method that contains the hostname before a TLS handshake is established.

Within the `servername_callback` method you can then chose what certificate to load based on the hostname.

###### Working solution

```py
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver
import ssl

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.write('Hello, world')

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/', MainHandler)
])

def servername_callback(sock, hostname, cb_context):
    # hostname contains the hostname that the client is requesting
    print("hostname", hostname)

    # now that we have the hostname we can dynamically pick the correct certificate
    ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    # this part is up to you to store via a config file or even in a database
    ssl_context.load_cert_chain(certfile="/path/to/cert", keyfile="/path/to/key")

    sock.context = ssl_context

if __name__ == '__main__':

    ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    ssl_context.sni_callback = servername_callback

    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application, ssl_options=ssl_context)
    http_server.listen(443)

    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```